# What do I need to do to make my apps compliant with OAuth 2.0 before 2011-12-13?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I just got this email from Facebook:

> Dear Developer,
>
> As part of our continued efforts to migrate all apps to OAuth 2.0, we
>   opted in all apps using the new JavaScript SDK to OAuth 2.0 this
>   afternoon at 11am PT and reverted at 1:30pm because we noticed that
>   your app has not migrated. Please ensure that you have set the oauth
>   param in FB.init to true and that you are using FB.getAuthResponse to
>   obtain the access token.
>
> Read more in the OAuth2 migration announcement, updates to the new JS
>   SDK blog post, or our JS SDK docs.
>
> If your app was affected today, please ensure that you have made these
>   changes by December 13th, 2012 to avoid any disruption with your
>   users.

The email doesn't specify which app needs my attention, and I can't make heads or tails of it.

Can anyone tell me what I need to be doing here? I have seven apps:

- Four were created solely because I needed an app ID (API key) to install the "Like" button on various sites. Do I need to add "oauth: true" to the FB.init() call on these pages? (None of them actually integrate with Facebook authentication. All they do is render Like/Send buttons, and hook into the Edge.create callback for tracking purposes.)
- Two of my apps are just tabs that I've added to Facebook Pages, which pull in static HTML pages (hosted elsewhere) via iframe. There's no JavaScript or server-side code whatsoever. I presume I can leave these alone?
- One is an off-the-shelf app from a third-party provider. Looking at their code, I see that their call to FB.init() already includes oauth: true.

Facebook does a really terrible job with developer documentation, explaining changes, and maintaining backward compatibility. I'm a pretty experienced developer, but it seems like you have to learn every nook and cranny of Facebook's (ever-changing and over-complicated) proprietary API suite just to use the simplest features. I'm not a Facebook app developer (and I don't want to become one); I'm just a guy who wants to use a few "Like" buttons and custom page tabs, preferably without having to wade through this nonsense every two months when Facebook decides to change everything around and break backward compatibility again.

Anyway, any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't see any of the blog posts since May - here's a summary: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/

To answer your specific questions, the 4 apps used only for the social plugins don't really USE oauth - but adding the oauth:true param and making sure they still work shouldn't be a huge issue - it also explicitly indicates to facebook that you're using the new auth mechanisms on those app IDs, so you shouldn't have an email sent about those apps in future

If your other apps aren't actually using any authentication, you probably don't need to do anything - if there was a problem you'd have discovered it yesterday when the oauth migration was flipped on for apps - the non compliant apps would have ceased working correctly